# Restricting IIS Access by IP

Tags: iis-7

I have a web page that will be displayed by an iframe called from another web server in an entirely different domain.  I only want this page displayed if its is being called by that domain server.

Is it possible to configure IIS 7 to only respond to those servers in a defined  domain or IP range?

Thanks

Comment: The Web doesn't work like that. The contents of the iframe will typically be loaded by the web browser, not the third party server. If you want to create this restriction, you will have to do it within your application code.

Comment: is there any way to do what I am describing?

Comment: Of course. But it's not something that we generally deal with at Server Fault. If you want to ask a question about developing your application, you may want to visit our sister site Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

Michael, look into the IP Address and Domain Restriction module in IIS for creating IP ranges that you can allow/disallow access to your site.

*note you may need to go into the Web Roles interface and enable this feature and restart IIS.